# receive duplicate values in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href ="java.css"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript">

function meal(){ 
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('checkboxes');
    var i=0;
    var j=0;
    var dish = [
    ["Boiled eggs","Eggs"],
    ["BLT Sandwich","Bacon"],
    ["BLT Sandwich","Lettuce"],
    ["BLT Sandwich","Tomato"],
    ["BLT Sandwich","Bread"],
    ["American Breakfast","Eggs"],
    ["American Breakfast","Bacon"],
    ["American Breakfast","Bread"],
    ["French Fries","Patatoes"]
    ];
    var content = "";
    for (i=0 ; i < dish.length; i++){
        for(j=0 ; j< checkboxes.length; j++){
            if ((dish[i][1] == checkboxes[j].value)&&(checkboxes[j].checked)){
            content+= dish[i][0] + '<br>';
            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = content;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>


<div id="big_one"> 
    <header id="Welcome">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
    </header>
    <div id= "new_div">

    <section id="check_boxes">
        <article >
            <header>
                <form name="ingredient">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="Eggs"> Eggs <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="Bacon"> Bacon <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="Lettuce"> Lettuce <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="Tomato"> Tomato <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="Bread"> Bread <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="Patatoes"> Patatoes </br>
                </form>
            </header>

        </article>
        <article >
            <header>
                <form name="Button">
                    <input type="button" name="Check" onClick="meal()" value="Search">
                </form>
            </header>

        </article>

    </section>

    <div id="result">
    </div>

    </div>
    <footer id="the_footer">
        Copyright &#169 Dejan Ivanov
    </footer>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The idea of this code is:
If I choose "eggs" to show me only dish "boiled eggs", if I choose "Eggs","Bacon" and "Bread" to show me dishes "boiled eggs" and "American breakfast", but program show me "boiled eggs", twice "BLT Sandwich" and triple "American breakfast"

```
For example if the known recipes are:
Boiled eggs -> Eggs
BLT Sandwich -> Bacon, Lettuce, Tomato, Bread
American Breakfast -> Eggs, Bacon, Bread

and the available ingredients are:
Bread, Eggs and Bacon

The search result should be:
Boiled eggs
American Breakfast
```

Could you please help me to fix this problem in the Javascript code.

Comment: Just wondering if my answer worked for you...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ought to do the trick for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/itsmikem/4EJb7/27/
If it works for you, please let me know.

I had to change your html and javascript quite a bit:

HTML:

```
<div id="big_one">
    <header id="Welcome">
         <h1>Welcome</h1>

    </header>
    <div id="new_div">
        <section id="check_boxes">
            <article>
                <header>
                    <form name="ingredient">
                        <!--Wrapping the input in a <label> tag makes the word clickable, too, not just the checkbox-->
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="">Eggs</label>
                        <br>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="">Bacon</label>
                        <br>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="">Lettuce</label>
                        <br>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="">Tomato</label>
                        <br>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="">Bread</label>
                        <br>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="">Potatoes</label>
                        <br>
                    </form>
                </header>
            </article>
            <article>
                <header>
                    <form>
                        <input id="gatherIngredients" type="button" onClick="meal();" value="Search">
                    </form>
                </header>
            </article>
        </section>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </div>
```

javascript:

```
// initialize the following lines once on the page so you don't have to do this every time you run the dish search:
// your data:
var allDishes = [
    ["Boiled eggs", ["Eggs"]],
    ["BLT Sandwich", ["Bacon", "Lettuce", "Tomato", "Bread"]],
    ["American Breakfast", ["Eggs", "Bacon", "Bread"]],
    ["French Fries", ["Potatoes"]]
];
// assemble a list of references to all of the checkboxes:
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
// tell the Search button to run the function "meal" when you click it:
document.getElementById("gatherIngredients").addEventListener("click", meal);
// this runs when the Search button is clicked:
function meal() {
    // STEP 1: make a record of all the ingredients you've selected:
    var selectedIngredients = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        // ensure that your text on the page matches exactly what the value is, so you won't get an error if you misspell one of the ingredients
        var newVal = String(checkboxes[i].parentNode.textContent).replace(/^[ \W]+|[ \W]+$/, "");
        checkboxes[i].value = newVal;
        //        alert(String("X" + newVal + "Y"));
        //checkboxes[i].value = "sal";
        // alert(checkboxes[i].value);
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
            // this item was checked, so add it to selectedIngredients
            selectedIngredients.push(checkboxes[i].value);
        }
    }
    // STEP 2: determine if each ingredient that was selected also has available all the other ingredients available to make any of the dishes
    var dishesThatCanBeMade = [];
    for (var eachIngredient = 0; eachIngredient < selectedIngredients.length; eachIngredient++) {
        // Let's start off by assuming all ingredients needed for each dish are selected. If one ingredient is not selected, this turns false.
        var allIngredientsAreAvailable = true;
        var thisIngredient = selectedIngredients[eachIngredient];
        // check each dish...
        for (var eachDish = 0; eachDish < allDishes.length; eachDish++) {
            var allIngredientsNeededForThisDish = allDishes[eachDish][1];
            // does this dish have this selected ingredient?       
            if (allIngredientsNeededForThisDish.indexOf(thisIngredient) != -1) {
                // alert(thisIngredient + " is an ingredient in " + allDishes[eachDish][0] + ", which calls for " + allIngredientsNeededForThisDish + ".");
                // yes, this dish has this ingredient, but have all the other ingredients been checked off as well?
                for (var everyOtherIngredient = 0; everyOtherIngredient < allIngredientsNeededForThisDish.length; everyOtherIngredient++) {
                    if (selectedIngredients.indexOf(allIngredientsNeededForThisDish[everyOtherIngredient]) == -1) {
                        allIngredientsAreAvailable = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (allIngredientsAreAvailable == true) {
                    // if the dish isn't already in the list, add it:
                    var thisDish = allDishes[eachDish][0];
                    if (dishesThatCanBeMade.indexOf(thisDish) == -1) {
                        dishesThatCanBeMade.push(thisDish);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    var theResults = "With the ingredients available to you:<br>";
    theResults += selectedIngredients.join(", ");
    theResults += "<br><br>you can prepare the following dishes:<br>";
    theResults += dishesThatCanBeMade.join(", ");
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = theResults;
}
```

Comment: Hello, the problem with dublicate values is fixed, but the problem with selection is still there in http://jsfiddle.net/itsmikem/4EJb7/. On my computer this script doesnot work. When I choose "EGGS" Should see only "Boiled eggs", but the result is 'Boiled Eggs' and 'American Breskfast'. The idia is when I have eggs I can cook only 'Boiled Eggs". Can you help for this problem.

Comment: Yes, I'll be glad to help.  I can't get to it today, can you wait until tomorrow?

Comment: Hi Dejan.  Can you please clarify what you mean by a selection problem?  In your original data, selecting "eggs" would show "boiled eggs" and "american breakfast". How doesn't it work on your computer?  What browser are you using?  Do you know where the code is breaking?  You can alter my fiddle, too, by adding in some alert functions.

Comment: It will help if you can clarify the logic to me what you want to show up in the results.  Shouldn't eggs give the result of "boiled eggs" and "american breakfast?"  Please try to be clear about why or why not and then I can help you more.

Comment: To be more specific I'll explain it like this: if I have in fridge only eggs I can cook only Boiled Eggs. For American Brekfast I don't have products. Thanks

Comment: OK, I think I get it now.  So am I right in assuming that if it's checked, then ALL of the ingredients have to be checked in order for it to output that meal, right?

Comment: Yes that is right. That is the condition. I will be great if you show me how to do it. Thanks

Comment: No problem...I'll be able to get to it within the next couple of days and I'll comment the code so you can understand.

Comment: Hi Dejan.  I had to rewrite the code quite a bit, and it works now.  I commented it as best I could to help you to step by step understand how it works.  It works just as I understand that if you don't have all the ingredients, you can't make the dish.  I edited my original answer: just click the link to see the updated fiddle.  Let me know if it works for you as you want.  And, if so, please remember to check off the answer so that the question is "closed" so others will know you're all set with it.  Let me know!  Glad to help you.

Comment: The script is wotking perfectly. Thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: Excellent Dejan!  I'm glad to hear it.  Could I ask you to please check off my answer?  This way, other users know you're set with the question.  Thanks!  And you gain I think 2 points doing that too.  :-)